# Produce whitespace-free CSS string with SASS @while loop

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm attempting to write a mixin that repeats a string as part of a selector. My desired output is very whitespace sensitive, but I can't find a way of making SASS compile without introducing said whitespace.

The desired output would be:

```
body:nth-child(n):nth-child(n){
  background: blue;
}

body:nth-child(n){
  background: green;
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

And I would like to achieve it using this invocation:

```
body {
  @include increase-specificity( 2 ){
    background: blue;
  }

  @include increase-specificity{
    background: green;
  }

  background: red;
}
```

The problem is that the `:nth-child(n)` string can't accept any whitespace after the current selector (`&`), or between repetitions, without changing the functional CSS afterwards – and I can't find a way of writing a mixin that fulfils this without causing SASS errors.

This is how I've tried to express the mixin:

```
@mixin increase-specificity( $depth: 1 ){
  &@while($depth > 0){#{'nth-child(n)'}$depth: $depth-1}{
    @content;
  }
}
```

[And here's a Codepen to show it breaking](http://cdpn.io/zLGlI).

My problems *so far* are:

- SASS won't tolerate the `@while` loop immediately following `&` (`&@while{`…), but I can't think of any other way to avoid whitespace between the compiled strings.
- Similarly, I can't find a way of writing a functonal `@while` loop without being liberal with whitespace: the current syntax falls over when it reaches the end of the the interpolator (`#{…}`) (don't know why), but removing interpolation causes it to trip up trying to interpret `nth-child`'s parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's so much going on wrong in your code (bad logic, missing whitespace, mismatched brackets, etc.), it's not worth the effort to try and explain why it doesn't work.

```
@mixin increase-specificity( $depth: 1 ) {
  $sel: '';
  @while($depth > 0) {
    $sel: $sel + ':nth-child(n)';
    $depth: $depth - 1;
  }
  &#{$sel} {
    @content;
  }
}

body {
    @include increase-specificity( 2 ){
        background: blue;
    }

    @include increase-specificity{
        background: green;
    }

    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the parse errors are *because* of the missing whitespace, which was the problem in the first place – can't express tersely without it – but the mismatched brackets threw me a bit. The logic seems OK (I always thought the point of Ruby was that you didn't have to do variable assignments and verbose concatenation, etc – but then I suppose you need whitespace!), but I'll take your word for it – thanks for a working solution!

Comment: Sass isn't Ruby, it is just a parser *written* in Ruby.

Comment: You're right – the similarities are incidental and not indicative.